Entity Framework Core / SQL Server Express returning byte array instead of string on m1 mac parallels
Wondering if anyone else is running into an issue with Entity Framework Core throwing an error when reading data from a local SQL Server Express instance that's running on an m1 mac and Parallels?
I get the following error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'

The database columns datatypes are all nvarchar, int, or bit. When I change my connection string to our remote SQL Server, there are no issues. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
I'm following the recent KB article provided by Parallels to use a local SQL Server Express instance. I copied the database from our remote SQL Server to local for development.
Article here: https://kb.parallels.com/129699/

I figured it out... When I copied the database it had carried over the encryption too. Removing this addressed the issue.
